# Print multiple rows returned by mysql to php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a php web page which will query the mysql db and mysql might return more than 1 row.
I want to print those rows one after another.

```
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tables WHERE name = 'table1';";
        $req = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($req);
```

I want to print something like this

```
 Poem_id   |   Poem_content  |  Poem_by  |   Poem_hotscore
------------ ----------------- ----------- -----------------
    1      |  Blah Bleh<br>B.|     4     |  5342.3920349
    7      |  Blah Bluu<br>F.|     4     |  5003.3920382
    9      |  Blerp Bloop Foo|    34     |  4300.7281209
```

Comment: Create HTML table and fill it with your data : )

Comment: One quick search online gave me [this link](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-select-query.php). SO requires you to do some research, and study the topic, before you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($req)) !== NULL)
    echo $res["Poem_id"]." | ".$res["Poem_content"]."<br />"; // and so on
```

Please note that php array keys are case sensitive. So there's a difference between

```
$res["Poem_id"]
```

and

```
$res["poem_id"]
```

Also don't forget to use htmlentities().